# Can I take a home baked Christmas cake into Australia?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, australia, food-and-drink

I have baked a large rich fruit cake decorated with marzipan and sugar icing for my son and his family.
Can I bring it with me into Australia?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bread, breakfast bar or canned food are allowed to be brought into australia?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/19960/bread-breakfast-bar-or-canned-food-are-allowed-to-be-brought-into-australia)

Comment: @JanDoggen Seems wrong to close this as a duplicate to a question which has itself been closed as unclear.

Comment: The official guidance http://www.agriculture.gov.au/travelling/arriving-in-australia is rather unclear although it seems to focus on uncooked products (apart from airline meals).

Comment: @MJeffryes IMO both the duplicate linked question and it’s answer are very clear.

Comment: @HonoraryWorldCitizen I agree, but if the other one is closed, this one should certainly not be.

Comment: The Aussie authorities are NOTORIOUSLY tough about foodstuffs arriving.  Nobody knows why this is, but it's just one of those strange things.  You will, almost certainly, struggle to do this.

Comment: @Fattie It is neither strange nor a secret why Australians are so strict on this issue. Being an isolated island, they don't have many diseases, pests and parasites common in agriculture in most other parts of the world and they are doing their justified best to prevent them from being introduced.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo , fair enough, that's one viewpoint; the other is it is prosaic and bucolic. Anyway, the point for this question is that they are famously notoriously tough, bureaucratic, regarding anything food related on arrival.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo Yes, of course, because we all know of the fruitcake bug and of marzipan blight. Sometimes rules just exist because some politician wanted to meddle.

Answer (score 9):

The Australian Border Force has a new web site on [what you can bring to Australia](https://www.abf.gov.au/entering-and-leaving-australia/can-you-bring-it-in).  Under "Top items" you'll find this:

[image: Homemade food - Meals, cakes or anything you made yourself can generally not come.]

Answer (score 5):

Maybe, maybe not. It is unfortunately difficult to tell in advance.

mdewey already linked to the [relevant page](http://www.agriculture.gov.au/travelling/arriving-in-australia#meat-poultry-and-seafood-products) from the Australian Department of Agriculture. They only give you guidance on which products you have to *declare*. If in doubt, you should declare any kind of food, plant or animal matter when entering Australia. They have very strict rules on what is allowed to import and the penalties can be quite severe if you fail to declare something.

I don't know the exact content of your fruit cake, but it will likely contain some of the following products, which have to be declared:

- fresh, frozen or dried fruits
- herbs and spices
- egg

After you have *declared* the food on arrival, it will be inspected by a biosecurity officer, who on a case-by-case basis will decide if you are allowed to take it in or not.

Comment: If allowed: fine. But this answer should include a) the fate of the cake and b) the fate of the cake's carrier if the cake is not allowed.

Comment: If you have declared, if the cake is not allowed it will be destroyed but there will be no problems for the carrier of it. If not declared, but found, the cake will still be destroyed and the carrier will face stiff fines and can be facing more actions (of which I am not sure at this time.)

Comment: I suppose someone having a bad day could say marzipan fell under the rubric of nuts to add to your list of ingredients.

Comment: @mdewey They don't have to be difficult to complain about marzipan. It's not made of nuts, but of seeds (almonds), which is also listed as an item you have to declare.

Comment: @simon at rcl: as long as you declare your food stuffs, you can pretty much bring anything. They'll just confiscate and destroy it if it's judged to not be acceptable. You won't get any penalty if you declare. If you don't declare but try to sneak things in though, things get complicated quickly (I live in Australia, and regularly carry food across the border).